# Is there a function that can convert numbers inputted from char array to an int array?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to pass an array through an overloaded function. The array is a string of numbers separated by spaces. I am trying to convert the char array into an int array as I have another function that is being called with a pointer to a char.

Here is my current solution. I tried to copy each element individually to an int array however when I try to read from that array I get a bunch of garbage numbers. 
It passes into the correct overloaded function that I have created.

```
  char str[100];             //string with inputted ints
int numStr[100];
int i = 0;
int count = 0;

fgets(str, 100, stdin);

while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        count++;
    }
    i++;
}
if (count >= 1)       //checks if there is more then one int
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        numStr[i] = str[i];
        numStr[i] = numStr[i] - '/0';
    }
    printf("Going into the int array function\n");
    assessGrade(numStr);    //passing int array
}
```

The program should get each number that is in between the spaces to copy into another int array together.

Comment: Use `strtok` to separate the numbers, and `strtol` to convert each number.

Comment: Using both `strtok` and `strtol` is unnecessary. `strtol` provides the `endptr` parameter to allow conversion of multiple values from a single buffer.

Comment: Are you wanting to limit yourself to only converting single digits `0-9`? Or do you need to be able to convert any integer value within the buffer (e.g. `9231867`)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin any integer. Its grades so they can range from 0-100.

Comment: What is an "overloaded function" in your context? In C there is no such thing as overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[100];
int numStr[100]; 
char *token;
int count = 0;
int spaceCounter = 0;

fgets(str, 100, stdin);

int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        spaceCounter++;
    }
    i++;
}
if (spaceCounter >= 1)       //checks if there is more then one int
{
    token = strtok(str, " ");

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        //printf("%s \n", token);
        numStr[count] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        count++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: So taking in all the information that I got from everyone last night this is what I have come up with. Looking at it now it should have been pretty straight forward in my opinion.

I realized that taking the data and separating them into tokens and then converting them to ints using atoi works efficiently and is simple enough to understand and walk through.

Thanks to everyone for you responses, it really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Let simplify your problem.

First suppose we have an char array that holds numbers: `char str[100]="1 2 3 4 5 6";` instead of fill it from input.

by performing this, and some little change we have:

---

***Code***

```
char str[100]="1 2 3 4 5 6";             //string with inputted ints
int numStr[100]={0};
int i = 0;
int count = 0;

while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] != ' ')
    {
        numStr[count]=str[i]-'0';
        count++;
    }
    i++;
}   
for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", numStr[i]);
}
```

---

Now we have numbers indexed from ***[0:count]*** in `numStr` integer array.

Comment: Ok this works for numbers that are not higher then the 10s place value. If I input anything higher then it separates those numbers.
i.e. if input was randomized { "23 103 45 -23 45" }

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

long *numbersToArray(const char *str, long *len) {
    const char *pos;
    char *endptr;
    long size, count, *ret, *tmp;
    size = 4;
    count = 0;
    ret = calloc(size, sizeof(long));
    if (!ret) return NULL;
    pos = str;
    while (isspace(pos[0])) ++pos;
    while (pos[0]) {
        if (count == size) {
            size += 4;
            tmp = realloc(ret, size * sizeof(long));
            if (tmp) ret = tmp;
            else {
                free(ret);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        ret[count] = strtol(pos, &endptr, 0);
        // if (errno) ...
        ++count;
        pos = endptr;
        while (isspace(pos[0])) ++pos;
    }
    if (len) *len = count;
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s numbers\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    long *arr, len, i;
    arr = numbersToArray(argv[1], &len);
    for (i = 0L; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("%ld\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your comment on being able to convert any integer value representation in the buffer to an integer, there is no substitute for `strtol`. While you can use `sscanf` employing the `%n` specifier to get the number of characters consumed to know how much to advance a pointer -- why? Any of your `scanf` conversions have virtually no error reporting capability beyond succeed/fail. `strtol` has the built in ability to work down a buffer converting values to `long` as you go.

How? The prototype for `strtol` is:

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

Where the string containing the numbers is provided by `nptr`, `endptr` will be set to one character past the last digit used following a successful conversion, and `base` provides the base of the number of convert (e.g. base `2, 8, 10, 16`, etc..) where a base of `0` will allow conversion from octal, decimal or hex depending on whether the string representation begins is `0` (octal) or `0x` (hex) or `1-9` (decimal).

So if you give `strtol` a string containing a number, on successful conversion, the return is a `long` value that can be tested against `INT_MIN/INT_MAX` to determine if it is in the range of `int`, `endptr` will be set to one past the last digit converted (set up to use for the next value) and all you need to is set `p = endptr;` and keep going.

Further, you know if `nptr == endptr` after the conversion -- no digits were converted. `strtol` also sets `errno` on overflow/underflow so you have a way to validate successful conversion to `long`. Further, should you want to check what is coming next, `endptr` points to the beginning character of the rest of what is contained in your buffer. You know down to the character what happened with the conversion and what remains to be converted.

So how do you put this into use? It's really straight forward. First let's define a couple of constants for the number of integers in the array and the maximum number of characters in your buffer, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for strtol   */
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN/INT_MAX */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno    */

#define ARSZ  100
#define MAXC 1024
```

Now declare your array, your buffer to hold your input, and a counter to keep track of the number of integer values converted and stored in the array:

```
    int arr[ARSZ] = {0};
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    size_t n = 0;
```

Now let's open a file for reading with the filename provided as the 1st argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided) and validate we have a valid open file stream, e.g.

```
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now it's time to get down to the business of reading lines of input and converting any character references to numeric values to `long` with `strtol`. First, read a line of input into your buffer with `fgets` and declare your `nptr` (shortened to `p`), `endptr` and a temporary `long` value `tmp` to hold the return from `strtol`, e.g.

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line of input */
        char *p = buf, *endptr;         /* nptr & endptr for strtol */
        long tmp;                       /* temp long for strtol */
```

With a line of input, you now proceed to loop converting values with `strtol`, validating that (1) digits were converted, (2) no overflow/underflow occurred (e.g. the value fit in `long`), (3) that the value is within the range of `int`, or (4) warn that the value exceeded the size of `int`. (we will talk about the `nextdigit` helper function later):

```
        /* protect array bounds, loop while not end of buf */
        while (n < ARSZ && *p && *p != '\n') {
            errno = 0;                      /* reset errno each iteration */
            tmp = strtol (p, &endptr, 0);   /* call strtol, update endptr */

            if (p == endptr)    /* validate digits converted */
                fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
            else if (errno)     /* validate conversion */
                fputs ("error: over/underflow occurred.\n", stderr);
            /* validate tmp is in range of integer */
            else if (INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX)
                arr[n++] = tmp;
            else
                fputs ("error: value exceeds range of int.\n", stderr);

            if (!(p = (char *)nextdigit (endptr)))  /* get next digit */
                break;
        }
```

(**note:** the conditions of the `while` loop, `n < ARSZ` -- don't store more integers than you have space for, while `*p && *p != '\n'` (your not at the end of string, e.g. the *nul-character* or the newline). You can omit the newline check, and it will be harmlessly handled in the body of the loop, but why? A simple check avoids the body of the loop altogether)

What is the `nextdigit()` helper function? From your reading of the [strtol(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html), you know that `strtol` will skip any leading whitespace up to the beginning of the next number to convert, but what if you have a comma-separated file, or other characters between your numbers? Very simple to handle, just scan forward in your buffer, checking characters as you go until your find the next `0-9`, or you find the next `+/-` and the next character after the explicit sign is a `0-9`.

That's all `nextdigit` does, returning the address of the beginning of the next value to convert, or `NULL` if there are no further digits to convert.

```
/* scan forward in 'p' to find next valid signed integer beginning */
const char *nextdigit (const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        if (('0' <= *p && *p <= '9') || 
            ((*p == '-' || *p == '+') && '0' <= *(p + 1) && *(p + 1) <= '9'))
            return p;
        p++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

(**note:** you can, and should, include `ctype.h` and replace the check of `('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')` with a simple `isdigit(*p)`, and the same with `isdigit(*(p+1))`, but the complete manual test was shown for illustration purposes)

Note in the code how `endptr` (the starting address for the scan forward) is passed to `nextdigit()`, and the result is the assigned to `p` and validated not `NULL` before the next iteration begins (with `p` primed to be passed to `strtol` again for the next conversion) -- rinse and repeat until you run out of characters in your buffer.

Approaching converting a buffer to integer values in this manner allows you to pick out and convert all integer values in the line -- regardless how messy the format.

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for strtol   */
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN/INT_MAX */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno    */

#define ARSZ  100
#define MAXC 1024

/* scan forward in 'p' to find next valid signed integer beginning */
const char *nextdigit (const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        if (('0' <= *p && *p <= '9') || 
            ((*p == '-' || *p == '+') && '0' <= *(p + 1) && *(p + 1) <= '9'))
            return p;
        p++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int arr[ARSZ] = {0};
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    size_t n = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line of input */
        char *p = buf, *endptr;         /* nptr & endptr for strtol */
        long tmp;                       /* temp long for strtol */

        /* protect array bounds, loop while not end of buf */
        while (n < ARSZ && *p && *p != '\n') {
            errno = 0;                      /* reset errno each iteration */
            tmp = strtol (p, &endptr, 0);   /* call strtol, update endptr */

            if (p == endptr)    /* validate digits converted */
                fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
            else if (errno)     /* validate conversion */
                fputs ("error: over/underflow occurred.\n", stderr);
            /* validate tmp is in range of integer */
            else if (INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX)
                arr[n++] = tmp;
            else
                fputs ("error: value exceeds range of int.\n", stderr);

            if (!(p = (char *)nextdigit (endptr)))  /* get next digit */
                break;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {    /* output results */
        if (i && i %10 == 0)            /* 10-values per row */
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %4d", arr[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

Now lets looks at the lines this approach can handle converting to integer values, e.g.

**Example Input Files**

Space separated values:

```
$ cat dat/10int_space.txt
8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495
```

Newline separated values:

```
$ cat dat/10int_nl.txt
8572
-2213
6434
16330
3034
12346
4855
16985
11250
1495
```

Integers within a mess:

```
$ cat dat/10intmess.txt
8572,;a -2213,;--a 6434,;
a- 16330,;a

- The Quick
Brown%3034 Fox
12346Jumps Over
A
4855,;*;Lazy 16985/,;a
Dog.
11250
1495
```

**Example Use/Output**

How does the conversion routine fair?

Space separated:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol_any_fixed <dat/10int_space.txt
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495
```

Newline separated:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol_any_fixed <dat/10int_nl.txt
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495
```

The unholy mess:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol_any_fixed <dat/10intmess.txt
error: no digits converted.
error: no digits converted.
error: no digits converted.
error: no digits converted.
error: no digits converted.
 8572 -2213 6434 16330 3034 12346 4855 16985 11250 1495
```

All values, whether space separated, newline separated, or whether sprinkled in the middle of "A quick brown fox...", were converted correctly.

Take time to digest the man page for `strtol` and then digest how it is implemented above. Once you master `strtol` (and `strtoul` (for `unsigned long`), `strtod` (for `double`), etc.. -- they all work very much the same, there is virtually no numeric conversion you can't handle. Let me know if you have further questions.